# Not able to fetch result from hive transaction enabled table through spark-sql

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

**Background:-**

- I am using HDP with spark1.6.0 and hive 1.2.1

**Steps Followed:-**

**Create a hive table:-**

```
hive>
CREATE TABLE orctest(PROD_ID bigint, CUST_ID bigint, TIME_ID timestamp, CHANNEL_ID bigint, PROMO_ID bigint, QUANTITY_SOLD decimal(10,0), AMOUNT_SOLD decimal(10,0) ) CLUSTERED BY (PROD_ID) INTO 32 BUCKETS STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ( "orc.compress"="SNAPPY", "transactional"="true" );
```

**Insert records into orctest**

```
hive>
insert into orctest values(1, 1, '2016-08-02 21:36:54.000000000', 1, 1, 10, 10000);
```

**Try to access the orctest table from spark-shell**

```
scala>
val hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

val s = hiveContext.table("orctest")*
```

**Exception Thrown:-**

```
16/08/02 22:06:54 INFO OrcRelation: Listing hdfs://hadoop03:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/orctest on driver
16/08/02 22:06:54 
INFO OrcRelation: Listing hdfs://hadoop03:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/orctest/delta_0000005_0000005 on driver
**java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed**
at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalRelation.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation$$anonfun$1.apply(LogicalRelation.scala:38)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.<init>(LogicalRelation.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.LogicalRelation.copy(LogicalRelation.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveMetastoreCatalog.org$apache$spark$sql$hive$HiveMetastoreCatalog$$convertToOrcRelation(HiveMetastoreCatalog.scala:588)
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27171702/error-in-scala-compiler-java-lang-assertionerror-assertion-failed-even-when-p

Comment: Thanks krishna for your comment.
But I have not tried this with a scala project, I directly tried this in spark-shell.
My thoughts:-
If you create a hive table with transnational property as true then you can't able to access the content of the table though spark.(Please correct me if i was wrong)
PS: I am using HDP(Spark 1.6.0 and hive 1.2.1)

Comment: I too am facing a similar issue. I cannot load a transaction enabled table to a spark dataframe. Have you found a workaround for this problem? I have tried setting hive transaction properties using sqlContext.setConf() before trying to load. I also tried creating a view on the source transaction table and hitting the view from spark but to no avail

Answer (score 2):

Try setting : `hiveContext.setConf("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc", "false")`